# Multiple Set Quoted_identifier within one script takes the last one?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, error-handling

I'm using SQL Server 2019 and just found a weird behaviour.
Research has not gotten me anywhere further.

Can someone please explain this behaviour?

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; 
if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '1- quoted_identifier is on' else print '1- quoted_identifier is off';
BEGIN TRY 
    if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '2- quoted_identifier is on' else print '2- quoted_identifier is off';
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '3- quoted_identifier is on' else print '3- quoted_identifier is off';
    -- SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
    -- if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '4- quoted_identifier is on' else print '4- quoted_identifier is off';
END CATCH
```

Returns:

```
1- quoted_identifier is on
2- quoted_identifier is on
```

but the following code:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; 
if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '1- quoted_identifier is on' else print '1- quoted_identifier is off';
BEGIN TRY 
    if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '2- quoted_identifier is on' else print '2- quoted_identifier is off';
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '3- quoted_identifier is on' else print '3- quoted_identifier is off';
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
    if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '4- quoted_identifier is on' else print '4- quoted_identifier is off';
END CATCH
```

Returns:

```
1- quoted_identifier is off
2- quoted_identifier is off
```

Even though it isn't going into the catch!!!
I must be missing something.

I was even able to simplify the code to the most simple :

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; 
if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '1- quoted_identifier is on' else print '1- quoted_identifier is off';
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
if ((256 & @@options) = 256) print '2- quoted_identifier is on' else print '2- quoted_identifier is off';
```

Results:

```
1- quoted_identifier is off
2- quoted_identifier is off
```

I have some code that uses `FOR XML`, which requires me to set quoted Identifier ON, but I need to put it back to OFF, no matter if the XML portion succeeds or fails.  How would you do that?

My tests show that if I put the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` to off in the `CATCH`, the insert fails to say that my quoted identifier is not set properly although it is set at the beginning of the `TRY` to `ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Charlieface](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/220697/charlieface)'s answer seems to have explained appropriately the reason for the behavior you described when using `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`, so I'll just leave a method you could use if you needed to use it inside a SP:

### Suggested Solution

Isolate part of your batch on another procedure and call it from the one where the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` needs to be `OFF` like this: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5786d938108f16bc7319cdbccab9095f) - run on your computer on 2 different sessions for I couldn't make it run properly on dbfiddle.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I don't think "nondeterministic" is relevant, that just means that it can return different results depending on what's going on with the connection/server etc. The result you see in the final batch is perfectly explained when you think of `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` as a parse-time option, it doesn't change the currently running setting until you finish the batch

Comment: @Charlieface nice input. But since the result can be different, how can he trust that the `if ((256 & @@options) = 256)` condition was properly evaluated and use the result to decide whether `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON` or `OFF`?

Comment: It's telling you something slightly different than what you think. It doesn't tell you whether `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is on/off in the *parse* stage, it only tells you the current default on the connection (what setting would be in force if you execute a *new* batch without any `SET`). I don't think there is any way of showing the current parse-time setting, other than doing the obvious and looking for `SET` statements (remember they ignore `IF` blocks).

Answer (score 11):

[**This is by design:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> For a top-level ad-hoc batch parsing begins using the session's current setting for `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`. As the batch is parsed any occurrence of `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` will change the parsing behavior from that point on, and save that setting for the session. So after the batch is parsed and executed, the session's `QUOTED_IDENTIFER` setting will be set according to the last occurrence of `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` in the batch.

**The behaviour of `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is therefore dependent on the *parsing* of the batch, not the execution.** The default at the start of parsing the batch comes from the current connection settings.

**`@@OPTIONS` only shows you the current default,** that would be used if a batch was parsed. This is why SSMS always puts `SET` in a separate batch.

The execution of `SET` is not relevant to the behaviour of `@@OPTIONS`, except to change later batches' default.

---

[You can see this in action in a db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=123c1d14c3a94176412fe375b6d4366c)

```sql
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  on;
create table "select"(i int);
drop table "select";
GO

set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  off;
create table "select"(i int);
drop table "select";
--  Incorrect syntax near 'select'.
GO

set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  off;
if (1=0)
begin
    set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  on;
end
create table "select"(i int);
drop table "select";
GO

set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  on;
if (1=0)
begin
    set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER  off;
end
create table "select"(i int);
drop table "select";
-- Incorrect syntax near 'select'.
GO
```

Comment: I removed the explanation from my answer since yours seems to be more accurate, but I still don't get it. How come in this [Demonstration of how changes affect behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/options-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-demonstration-of-how-changes-affect-behavior) it captures the changes of `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` on the same batch without the need of isolating them with a `GO`?

Comment: `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` appears to work at execution time see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=407d161138172929b9f708e0aa457e18, whereas `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` does not

Comment: Woooooow! now I see the mess I was doing. I hadn't noticed the sample code on the `@@OPTION` doc was setting `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` instead of `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`. Thanks.